# How does the ISS Shenzhou have Same Tech as Prime Ships?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-discovery

In (TOS) "The Tholian Web" the USS Defiant (NCC-1764) got pulled into another dimension that we later find out (in Enterprise: “In a Mirror, Darkly”) is the Mirror Universe about 100 years in the past of TOS and is subsequently captured by the Terran Empire.

In (Discovery) "Despite Yourself" the USS Discovery (NCC-1031) is in the Mirror Universe and encounters the ISS Shenzhou (NCC-1227) with what appears to be just about exactly the same tech as the Prime Universe USS Shenzhou (NCC-1227) had.

So the Question is...

With about 100 years of time with a future ship from an alternate timeline how is it that the Empire did not develop significantly advanced technology and design far more advanced ships by reverse engineering the USS Defiant (NCC-1764) and going through its memory banks?

Examples of Alien Tech in Star Trek being reverse engineered in a short period are. (these may not be accurately remembered examples but the question still stands valid)

It only took roughly 30 years to develop the Mobile Emitter for the Doctor in (Voy) "Future's End, Part II" in 1996, something they hadn't even developed in own Voyagers Timeline. Not to mention the computer chip revolution that happened due to this.

In (Voy) "Endgame" Admiral Janeway Travels into the past and within days helps the Voyager develop and implement Technology that wasn't designed for their systems and significantly enhances Voyagers Defensive capabilities.

In (DS9) "Shattered Mirror" the Tarren Resistance Developed and built a Defiant using "acquired" specifications from DS9 in 2371, only needing Sisko's help at the end to fix the same structural issues that the Prime Sisko had when developing the ship.

Comment: I think the idea was that the Mirror Universe Federation, being Evil, couldn't possibly be as technologically capable as the Prime Universe Federation.  The *Defiant* is supposed to explain how they caught up.  Whether that makes sense is arguable, but that's my guess as to the writer's intent.

Comment: What is even more strange is: The empire subjugted the vulcans but did NOT gain their shield technology (see "In a mirror darkly" the Enterprise had NO shields, and still had only their energized hull). As harsh as it sounds I fear those are mostly thinking errors on the writers parts as neither happening (defiant not giving them more tech nor the vulcans giving them shield tech make sense to me).

Comment: I've had to clean up your tags, because as a rule all star-trek questions must carry the star-trek tag. I was also unsure which other tags to include, I've settled with just [star-trek-discover] as that's the show your question is _specifically_ about, even though it uses the others as a reference.

Comment: “how is it that the Empire did not develop significantly advanced technology and design far more advanced ships by reverse engineering the USS Defiant (NCC-1764)” — it’s difficult to get any reverse-engineering done when everyone’s murdering each other all the time.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite They seemingly did so already in pre shakespeare times....and still cochrane managed to get the warp drive done at the same time as his prime equivalent and archers ship also had the same technology, so I fear they were still quite adept at getting their tech done there despite the....short comings. Still though what is more shockig is ... they enslaved the vulcans and didn't get their shield tech during archers times....would have been the first thing I took from the long eared ones.

Comment: I’m making this a comment rather than an answer because I don’t have any canon source or word of god, but I always read the Mirror Universe as not just an alternate timeline but an actual dark reflection of the prime timeline with some unexplained force of nature keeping them in sync. There are far too many coincidences between the universes to explain otherwise (not least that the same people and ships exist despite centuries of change). As Lorca says, the two universe are the best argument for the existence of destiny he’s ever seen.

Comment: *"Examples of Alien Tech in Star Trek being reverse engineered in a short period are. "*   --  Yoda?   Wrong universe.

Comment: This is just one example of a broader problem with the entire Mirror Universe concept, in that the MU always seemed to track the Prime Universe rather closely, even when it makes no sense for it to do so. Even just the smallest deviation in events in the 22nd Century should have _easily_ rendered subsequent events such that the exact same people who exist in the 24th Century _would have little to no chance of even existing_ with the same DNA, family history, etc. Let alone being on the same space station in the same group. You have to allow for "time did it" hand-wavey rubbish sadly